# android convert emulated sdcard path to real sdcard path

Tags: android

from Environment I get paths like:

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

I need to convert it to the real path like

```
/storage/sdcard0
```

as I need to issue a shell command ( pm install ) which can not deal with /storage/emulated/0 - only with /storage/sdcard0 - any Idea how to get from one to the other?

Comment: can you check the content of the env variable \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE? `adb shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: thanks for the info: shell@android:/ $ echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE                                       
/storage/emulated/legacy

Comment: and that's not exactly what you want, I guess

Comment: It kind of shows a possible solution - thanks for this! But somehow I silently hoped for a java API to do the conversion and not having to look into a ENV variable

Comment: yes there is also a java call to get environment variable. `System.getenv` from java.lang.System

Comment: yea - it is more - can I rely on this env variable to be set every time and things like these - a real API for this would just feel better that is what I thought. But thanks anyway - your answer is better than nothing I had before!-)

Comment: I guess it depends on the manufacture, if it set or not. You can try to read and parse `/proc/mounts`.. you are welcome

Comment: yes that was my fear ;-) I want to reward your work - if you provide your answer as an answer, then I will upvote it for 10points and if no better answer pops up in 2 days I will accept it for 15p ;-)

Comment: It's ok.. let's wait for somebody else :), It's always an interesting topic

Comment: The quoted path is "real" however the real path now varies depending on who is asking.  It is one thing for apps (and their children) and something else for adb (even when impersonating a debug app with run-as).  /proc/mounts literally has different content depending on the ancestory of the process which reads it.